# How to make a timeout at receiving in boost::asio udp::socket?

Tags: c++, c++17, qt-creator, boost-asio

I create an one-thread application which exchanges with another one via UDP. When the second is disconnecting, my socket::receive_from blocks and I don't know how to solve this problem not changing the entire program into multi-threads or async interactions.

I thought that next may be a solution:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds timeout{4};
boost::system::error_code err;
data_t buffer(kPackageMaxSize);
std::size_t size = 0;

const auto status = std::async(std::launch::async,
    [&]{
        size = socket_.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), dst_, 0, err);
    }
).wait_for(timeout);

switch (status)
{
    case std::future_status::timeout: /*...*/ break;
}
```

But I achieved a new problem: Qt Creator (GDB 11.1) (I don't have ability to try something yet) began to fall when I am debugging. If it runs without, the solution also not always works.

Comment: ip::udp::socket::non_blocking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PS. As for "it doesn't work when debugging", debugging (specifically breakpoints) obviously changes timing. Also, keep in mind network operations have varying latency and UDP isn't a guaranteed protocol: messages may not be delivered.

---

Asio stands for "Asynchronous IO". As you might suspect, this means that asynchronous IO is a built-in feature, it's the entire *purpose* of the library. See overview/core/async.html: [Concurrency Without Threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html)

It's not necessary to complicate with `std::async`. In your case I'd suggest using `async_receive_from` with `use_future`, as it is closest to the model you opted for:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1dd5e047b0bf5c0)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
namespace net = boost::asio;
using net::ip::udp;

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
constexpr auto kPackageMaxSize = 65520;
using data_t = std::vector<char>;

int main() {
    net::thread_pool ioc;

    udp::socket socket_(ioc, udp::v4());
    socket_.bind({{}, 8989});

    udp::endpoint ep;
    data_t        buffer(kPackageMaxSize);
    auto          fut =
        socket_.async_receive_from(net::buffer(buffer), ep, net::use_future);

    switch (fut.wait_for(4ms)) {
        case std::future_status::ready: {
            buffer.resize(fut.get()); // never blocks here
            std::cout << "Received " << buffer.size() << " bytes: "
                      << std::quoted(
                             std::string_view(buffer.data(), buffer.size()))
                      << "\n";
            break;
        }
        case std::future_status::timeout:
        case std::future_status::deferred: {
            std::cout << "Timeout\n";
            socket_.cancel(); // stop the IO operation
            // fut.get() would throw system_error(net::error::operation_aborted)
            break;
        }
    }

    ioc.join();
}
```

The Coliru output:

```
Received 12 bytes: "Hello World
"
```

Locally demonstrating both timeout and successful path:

[image]

Comment: If you prefer you can use `system_executor{}` which ends up using implementation-defined threads, similarly to `std::async`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b66565b9eb22df3f